# Best way to persist join table data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

I've a scenario where I've a join created on top of 10 tables. This works great when the join is done in the database. Now, these tables are streaming data through Kafka topics (1:1 - table:topic mapping). I need to create/update the join(s) as the new messages come to the topic. So far, I've decided to store this data in a NoSQL DB like Cassandra and update the joined records as events keep coming. Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to do this within Kafka itself?
2. If not in Kafka, what is the best way to do that?
3. Does the solution of persisting in Cassandra offer a better alternative?

**Please Note:** I've read that Cassandra isn't the right solution for joins. If not Cassandra, what is recommended? Please don't shoot the question down being subjective because if not others, at least, I expect to gain insights with that as well.

Comment: You want to join the data flowing through 10 separate Kafka topics, and then insert into Cassandra?

You can join multiple topics using [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), but joining 10 separate streams could have some significant overheads.

As you mentioned, Cassandra cannot do joins. Generally you want to denormalise as much as possible when data modelling for Cassandra. You would start with a query that you want to make and build a table so that it can satisfy that query without requiring any joins.

Comment: @JustinCameron - Thank you for your input, would look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this within Kafka itself?

Yes, using Kafka Streams or KSQL.

- Kafka Streams [details](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/02/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/) and [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/PageViewRegionLambdaExample.java)
- KSQL [details and example](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/examples.html#joining)

As Justin Cameron noted, joins are limited to 2-way joins, so you would need to "daisy chain" your transformations. Each would write back to an staging Kafka topic, and the final joined result would also be a Kafka topic. From here, you can stream it to Cassandra using [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) (part of Apache Kafka).

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, the company behind the open-source KSQL project.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would go over the links that you shared and would come back to you with questions.